# Transactions: How to make them work with FireDAC and mySQL?

Tags: mysql, delphi, transactions, firedac

In the past I have successfully implemented transactions with FireDAC and MSSQL as follows:

```
  Con.StartTransaction;
  try

    //Insert database code here...

    Con.Transaction.Rollback; //change to .Commit after I make sure everything works....
  except
    on e : Exception do
    begin
      Con.Rollback;      
      ShowMessage('Save failed with message ' + e.Message);
    end;
  end;
```

However this same method does not work with MySQL (at least out of the box). To be specific the first rollback method in the sample code above does not roll back but the changes are made to the tables in spite of the rollback. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What table type do you use in mysql?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the type is MyISAM.

Comment: That's it. I see that MyISAM does not support transactions. Changed all the tables to InnoDB. Thank you.